# Escaping quote in xpath (python script)

Tags: python, xpath, scapy

I'm making a scapy script, using xpath, to collect some page informations.
I would like to extract the URL of the javascript :

```
<div class="is-hidden-mobile blEntry menu ui_link" data-column="3" onclick="widgetEvCall('handlers.onMenuClicked', event, this, 'http://www.zzz.com/')">
    <span class="ui_icon menu"></span>
    <span class="detail">Menu </span>
</div>
```

So I test this command :

```
substring-before(substring-after(//@onclick, "'handlers.onMenuClicked', event, this, '"),"'")
```

And it works in a Xpath tester.

But when I put it in my python script, I've the quote problem. So I tried to put backslash, but it's not working :

```
website =  response.xpath('substring-before(substring-after(//@onclick, "\'handlers.onMenuClicked\', event, this"),"\'")').extract()
```

I'm looking on the web, but I dont see any answer :S. I think my script is to complicate and can be simplified, but I dont know how xD. Or maybe there is a solution to have the simple quotes inside the script ...

Thanks for your help
REgards

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days looking for, I found the answer :D

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="is-hidden-mobile blEntry menu ui_link"]').re('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+')
```

I take all the xpath answer, and I extract the URL with a regex.

Regards